# unable to post with file upload using axios react js

Tags: reactjs, file, post, file-upload, axios

I am trying to post multi-part form data with file upload using React and Axios. I tried the same in Postman and this is working correctly. But in react, I get "Required request part 'file' is not present". My code:

```js
const selectedFile = event.target.file.files[0].name;

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name',this.state.name);
formData.append('description',this.state.description);
formData.append('file', selectedFile);
        
// Here I am passing content type and token and Post request . 
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/user/1/savecategory',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    'Authorization':`Bearer ${passToken}`,
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(
  (response) => {
    alert("Category Saved..!");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Failed..!");
  }
);
```

Comment: The answer below is indeed correct. I would recommend not handling the upload yourself as there are edge-cases and cross-browser issues to handle that in Production code you'd want to cover. A library such as [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady) takes care of all of that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't add the `file` field to the `FormData` Object. you only passed the name of the file as the second parameter.

de definition of `append` method is like this

For regular form field

> formData.append(name, value);

And for Field field you can add It using this syntax

> formData.append(name, value, filename);

Here `selectedFile` contain the name of the file which is selected in the file input field

```
const selectedFile = event.target.file.files[0].name;
```

When you call `formData.append('file', selectedFile);` you are passing the `name` of the file as value of the form element with name `file` and not the file It self.

to pass the file It self you should perform It like this

```
const selectedFile = event.target.file.files[0];
```

After that you can call `formData.append('file', selectedFile);`

Learn more about [FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)